# App loading wrong layout from folder

Tags: android, layout

I have a default `layout\` folder for all my layouts and `layout-hdpi\` for just one that is not displaying properly on lower resolutions. Problem is that my emulator with xxxhdpi and xxhdpi (haven't checked xhdpi) is accesing `layout.xml` from wrong folder `layout-hdpi\`. Why and how to fix it (besides creating `layout-xxxhdpi\` and `layout-xxhdpi\` for the same file)!?

Comment: CodeRed's answer below is correct: pixel density qualifiers don't behave like any other qualifiers and can be used by devices that don't "match". However, I'm curious _why_ you have **only** an `hdpi` folder for your layouts. That smells like a mistake to me.

Comment: I have default `layout` folder for all, and `hdpi` for just one that isn't displaying properly on devices with 480*800 resolution, that's why I changed that layout a bit and put it in `hdpi` folder

Comment: `hdpi` doesn't really have anything to do with screen resolution. It has to do with pixel density (e.g. how many `px` there are per `dp` on that particular device). You could have a 400x800 mdpi device and a 400x800 xxhdpi device. I recommend opening another question about what you saw that was wrong with your one layout on that one device; maybe you'll be able to get a better answer than using a `layout-hdpi` folder.

Comment: "You could have a 400x800 mdpi device and a 400x800 xxhdpi device." Hm this seems highly unlikely, any examples of such a device???

Comment: It's not about the real-world likelihood of something happening, it's about correct understanding of what the pixel density resource qualifier actually does.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very interesting behaviour, but as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) describes:

> **Note:** Using a density qualifier doesn't imply that the resources are only for screens of that density. If you don't provide alternative resources with qualifiers that better match the current device configuration, the system may use whichever resources are the best match.

And if you look a little bit further onto the chapter [How Android finds the best-matching resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#BestMatch) you will find the following:

> **Exception:** Screen pixel density is the one qualifier that is not eliminated due to a contradiction. Even though the screen density of the device is hdpi, drawable-port-ldpi/ isn't eliminated because every screen density is considered to be a match at this point. More information is available in the Supporting Multiple Screens document.

Comment: OK, but funny thing, before I did it with `layout-hdpi`, I created `layout-w480` folder with same `layout.xml` in it. What happened is that my default layout suddenly went landscape mode even though my app is in locked portrait mode